# Using 'Gravity' As A Verb

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Does anybody else use 'gravity' as a verb besides people in mining and engineering?

Example: We have to move the tank up the hill so water can gravity to the flotation cells rather than needing to be pumped.

Comment: I've never heard that usage - interesting!

Comment: Other possibilities are "gravitate" and "gravity-flow" and "flow downhill".

Answer (score 6):

OED has no entry for *gravity* as a verb. Dictionaries document usage, so it takes some time for them to catch up with a word's appearance, especially for a particular technical term.

Now that Google's Ngrams can analyse parts of speech, it's possible to see that *gravity_VERB* **does** appear in their database, although at a far lower incidence than ***gravitate***. [Reference](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gravitate,gravity_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) Unfortunately they don't add citations to their findings, so it's not possible to verify their parsing.

*Gravitate* tends to be used with *towards,* and more figuratively than literally. People may gravitate towards a celebrity in a room, for example; it doesn't mean he has a brain the size of a planet.

In the cited example, while there may be a technical use of *gravity* as a verb, most readers will baulk.

Answer (score 4):

[Verbing nouns](http://moreintelligentlife.com/content/ideas/anthony-gardner/youve-been-verbed) is a well-established practice in the English language, but some verbings are better accepted than others.

> Sometimes the results are ridiculous—notably when verbs are minted from nouns which were formed from verbs in the first place. To say “Let’s conference” instead of “Let’s confer” . . . makes the speaker seem either ignorant or pretentious. . . . Using an elaborate verb when there is a far simpler alternative – such as “dialogue” for “talk” – has the same effect.

Another common reason for rejecting a verbed noun is that there's already a suitable verb form – in this case, [*gravitate.*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gravitate) According to [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gravitate,gravity_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), English writers prefer *gravitate* to verbed *gravity* by an order of magnitude. You're unlikely to see it outside of jargon or other idiosyncratic writing.

Comment: Slightly OT, but I wonder whether 'verbing nouns' (which is, of course, itself verbing a noun!) is more prevalent in US usage than UK usage?

Answer (score 2):

No, *gravity* [is not a verb](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gravity).

In that usage it would be better to say something like *"...so that water will flow to the flotation cells under the force of gravity, rather than needing to be pumped."*

Comment: I am inclined along the same path of hesitation.  In the example, gravity is still a noun, as it is the description or identification of a named process.  The verb is 'can' which is to allow or to enable.